# How do I search and replace structurally in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, structural-search

I am migrating my Junit tests from Junit v3 to Junit v4.

I was hoping to use the search and replace structurally "srs" to add an @Test annotation before all methods starting with test.* using my favorite IDE Intellij.

I just cant figura out how to do it... I can create a query that will find all methods without an annotation (there is an example bundled in Intellij) but when used to do a replace either my class gets replaced by only the method names OR nothing is found.

Maybe a regexp is easier :-)

Comment: I was trying to search for double checked synchronized blocks earlier today. Maybe we should file a bug report; srs does not do what we need ?

Comment: Yeah I guess it is a bit cryptic to the untrained, I saw one sample that was implemented with groovy. How are a mere mortal like me going to use that?

Comment: I've tried to use it a number of times, without success.  It takes a while to figure out how to make expressions that match (even though I know quite a few RE systems), and then when applied, it deletes the target rather than substituting my replacement.

A few times, I've had to look for quite a while to find all the code scattered throughout my sources that was deleted.  It's more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, as of now, but there are requests for class members replacements.

Here is a useful link for getting started with ssr: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/ssr.pdf

Comment: Link to documentation is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the following SSR but I have the same problem than you :

Search template :

```
public class $TestCase$ extends $TestCaseClazz$ {
  public void $testMethod$();
}
```

Replacement template :

```
@Test public void $testMethod$();
```

And I check  "This variable is target of the search" on testMethod.
The preview seems ok, but IntelliJ actually delete the whole method :(

Answer (score 0):

Open Search -> Replace in path
Set Directory to the directory where your test is placed
Set search string to: public void test.
Set replace string to: @Test\n\tpublic void test.
Check Regular Expression box.

Enjoy.

Comment: Sorry not really the answer I was looking for. I was asking for the more powerful structural search. I have already done the replace using regexps.